# How do I calculate pvalue of each rows through t.test between two groups of dataframe,each group has 3 replicates, with thousands rows

Tags: r

cd4 is a dataframe of 3 columns, each column is a replicate, and thousands rows
cd8 is similar to cd4, with the same ncols and nrows.
I want to calculate the each row's p values between cd4 and cd8

```
pcal <- function(x,y){
  a <- t.test(x[,1:3], y[,1:3])
  pvalue <- a$p.value
  return(pvalue)
  }
map2(cd4, cd8, pcal)
```

#the code can't run and report

#<error/purrr_error_indexed>
#Error in `map2()`:
#ℹ In index: 1.
#ℹ With name: cd4t1.
#Caused by error in `x[, 1:3]`:
#! incorrect number of dimensions
`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knh8e.png)

I want to get the p value of cd4 and cd8 by rows, not by column

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use `asplit` first to split your data.frame by row.

```r
library(purrr)
map2_dbl(asplit(cd4,1), asplit(cd8,1), ~t.test(.x, .y)$p.value)
```